# Codeigniter module configuration and ACL

Tags: php, codeigniter, module

I am developing a site in codeigniter divided into modules using HMVC. I want the modules to be enabled/disabled by an administrator, and following is how I am planning to achieve it. Since I don't have much experience in PHP/Codeigniter, the following way could be very wrong, so am looking for suggestions/feedbacks:

DB Table: Modules
ID | NAME | STATE

Above table will contain all the module information, and the state field will contain the disabled/enabled value(0 or 1).

I am going to extend the main CI_Controller, and have a function to check the status of the module:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->Model('Module_model'); //loads the module model
}
function check_module_state($module_name = '')
{
return $this->Module_model->getState($module_name); //the model returns TRUE or FALSE
}
```

Now, in the constructor of every controller, I will extend the MY_Controller class, and call the `check_module_state` and if it returns FALSE, will redirect the user to a "Section Disabled Page";

```
class Module1 extends MY_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
if($this->check_module_state('module1') == FALSE)
redirect('module_disabled', 'location');
}
}
```

Will the above work, is there a better and easier alternative? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks ok. How you describe the functionality sounds good. I would however say that if a module is disabled it isn't necessary to tell people that it is disabled.

How I would approach this problem is as below.

I would use the module table to construct the navigation items. If a module is enabled allow a link to be displayed to that module. If the module is disabled no link is displayed. This would not mean you can get rid of security in your controllers as people may still URL Surf. In the case of URL Surfing to a disabled module I would silently re-direct to a default module, for example, the site root (Index).

Comment: Yes, not showing links to the disabled module is a good idea. Speaking of which, how can efficiently manage the menus? Do I call do this in the view files?
eg:
`if($this->Modules_model->isActive('module1') echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'module1/">module1</a>';` 
That way, I think it will call the database for all the modules to be shown on the menu. Or do I do call the database once, and store the modulenames and its state in an array, and subsequently check the array for the status?

Comment: @Damchey That is a possible solution yes. I don't use CI myself but if its anything like ZF and has support for site wide default layouts then you could stick your navigation stuff all in there.